# Pytest: Carthesian product of dependent fixtures

Tags: fixtures, pytest

Imagine the following testsuite

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=1, 2, 3)
def shape(request):
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture
def data(shape):
    return shape


def test_resize(data, shape):
    pass
```

where I have two fixtures `data` and `shape`. `data` depends on the fixture `shape` and is being generated for each of the possible values. But in `test_resize` I want to test over all possible combinations of `data` and `shape`:

- 1, 1
- 1, 2
- 1, 3
- 2, 1

etc. With the implementation above it does not expand the carthesian product though:

- 1, 1
- 2, 2
- 3, 3

Is there a way to make py.test expand the fixtures to all possible combinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your output shows, `shape` is parameterized but `data` is not, thus there will only be *one* instance of the `data` fixture for each instance of the `shape` fixture.  I would also parameterize `data`.  Then, still having the `data` fixture depend upon `shape`, you'll get the product you desire:

```
import pytest

fixture_params = (1, 2, 3)

@pytest.fixture(params=fixture_params)
def shape(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=fixture_params)
def data(request, shape):
    print(request.param)
    return request.param

def test_resize(data, shape):
    print(data, shape)
    assert 0 and 'assert to show prints'
```